# Phoenix/Ecto - restart identity in seedfile

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

When using the seedfile in a Phoenix app, is it possible to restart the identity for a table if the seed is run more than once?

For example, I'm currently working with the following seed:

```
PhoenixApp.Repo.delete_all PhoenixApp.Role
PhoenixApp.Repo.insert!(%PhoenixApp.Role{role: "admin"})
PhoenixApp.Repo.insert!(%PhoenixApp.Role{role: "non-admin"})
```

The first line clears the table (so that the records don't pile up if the seed is run multiple times), and the lines following create the seed records.  Running this code once would create two records with the autoincremented primary keys '1' and '2', as you would normally expect. However, if I want to add another entry to the table later on, such as

```
PhoenixApp.Repo.insert!(%PhoenixApp.Role{role: "superuser"})
```

the ids of the rows will now be '3', '4', and '5', because the identity was not restarted.

Does Ecto have a command that restarts the table identity as well? I realize that I could add additional records to my table via IEx, but I'd prefer to restart the identity, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you can execute `ALTER SEQUENCE <sequence name> RESTART` to reset the value of the sequence to its original value. The Sequence Name for the ID primary key will be `#{table_name}_id_seq`. You can run the query using `Repo.query`, for example:

```
Repo.query("ALTER SEQUENCE comments_id_seq RESTART")
```

```
iex(1)> Repo.insert!(%Comment{}).id
11
iex(2)> Repo.delete_all(Comment)
{11, nil}
iex(3)> Repo.insert!(%Comment{}).id
12
iex(4)> Repo.query("ALTER SEQUENCE comments_id_seq RESTART")
{:ok,
 %Postgrex.Result{columns: nil, command: :alter_sequence, connection_id: 3360,
  num_rows: 0, rows: nil}}
iex(5)> Repo.insert!(%Comment{}).id
1
```

Comment: Thanks again, @Dogbert!